# TFS 2010 and VS 2010 Professional - viewing code coverage results of team build?

Tags: tfs, code-coverage

### setup

1. TFS server 2010
2. Build server has visual studio premium edition
3. Dev machines have VS 2010 Professional

### What's working

1. Project file is set up to capture code coverage results.
2. Team build configured to run on every commit.
3. Team build output shows overall code coverage aggregate numbers (75% covered etc)

### What doesnt seem to be working

1. What I'd like to see is from developer machines, be able to see the coverage break up. From what I've read, seems like if I open a build run and in the build output, click the `View test results` link, it should show me the test results as well as the coverage results.

### What's actually happening

1. When I click on `View test results` from the dev machines, I get some XSD errors

I've searched high and low and:

1. Can't find any other references to these errors -  That suggests that I'm probably doing something silly. Any pointers?
2. I understand that VS premium or Ultimate edition is required for code coverage on the build server. But what I'd like to know is, **do I need VS premium/Ultimate for viewing code coverage results of a team build too?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess yes you will need it, because the coverage viewer is part of the code coverage component which is only exist in VS Premium/Ultimate.